# Haskell to Prolog or just Prolog delaunay triangulation

Tags: prolog

I have completed a haskell code to compute the delaunay triangulation of a given point set. However, now i am stuck as to how and what method needs to be completed in prolog

Haskell:

```
-- The type for a single point.
    type Point a = (a,a)

-- The type for a pair of points.
    type Pair a = (Point a, Point a)

-- The type for a triple of points.
    type Triple a = (Point a, Point a, Point a)

-- Predicate for a triple of 3 points is in CCW order or not
    isCCW :: Real a => Triple a -> Bool
    isCCW ((x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)) = (x2-x1)*(y3-y1)-(x3-x1)*(y2-y1) > 0

-- Convert a triple to a CCW triple 
    toCCW :: Real a => Triple a -> Triple a
    toCCW (p1, p2, p3) = if (isCCW ((( p1, p2, p3 )))) then (p1, p2, p3)
                 else (p1, p3, p2) 

-- Generate all pairs of points from a list of points.
-- Each pair should appear exactly once in the result.
    pairsFromPoints :: Real a => [Point a] -> [Pair a]
    pairsFromPoints [] = []
    pairsFromPoints (x:xs) = map makePair xs ++ (pairsFromPoints xs)
where makePair y = (x,y)

-- Generate all unique CCW triples of points from a list of points
-- Each triple should appear exactly once in the result and be
-- CCW ordered.
    triplesFromPoints :: Real a => [Point a] -> [Triple a]
    triplesFromPoints [] = []
    triplesFromPoints (x:xs) = map makeTriple (pairsFromPoints xs) ++ (triplesFromPoints xs)
        where makeTriple (y,z) = toCCW(x,y,z)
```

And this is the Prolog code that I'm stuck on.

Prolog:

```
% concatenate(L1, L1, T) is true if and only if T is equal to the concatenation
% of lists L1 and L2.
%
    concatenate(L1, L2, T).


% singletons(P, Q) is true if and only if Q is equivalent to the list obtained    
% from P if each item in P is wrapped in "[" and "]" to create a singleton list.
%
    singletons(P, Q).

% prefix_all(I, P, Q) is true if and only if P is a list of lists and Q is the
% list obtained by prepending I to each element in P.
%
    prefix_all(I, P, Q).

% pairs_all(I, P, Q) is true if and only if Q is the list obtained by pairing I
% with each item in P.
%
    pairs_all(I, P, Q).

% Predicate to test if three points are in counter-clockwise orientation.
%    
    is_ccw([[X1,Y1],[X2,Y2],[X3,Y3]]) :- (X2-X1)*(Y3-Y1)-(X3-X1)*(Y2-Y1) > 0.


% ccw(T, U) is true if and only if T and U are triples containing the same
% points and U is in counter-clockwise orientation.
%
    ccw(T, U).


% ccw_triples(P, Q) is true if and only if Q is the list containing all the
% triples of points in the list P except arranged in ccw orientation.
%
    ccw_triples(P, Q).


% pairs_of_points([H|T], Q) is true if and only if Q is a list containing all of
% the distinct pairs that can be made from the points in the list of points
% [H|T].
%
    pairs_of_points([H|T], Q).

% triples_of_points([H|T], Q) is true if and only if Q is a list containing all
% of the distinct triples that can be made from the points in the list of points
% [H|T].
%
    triples_of_points([H|T], X).


% is_delaunay_triangle(T, P) is true if and only if no point of the point set P
% is in the circle defined by the triple T (which here you may assume is in CCW
% orientation).  This predicate is undefined if P is empty.
%
    is_delaunay_triangle(T, P).


% delaunay_triangles(T, P, X) is true if and only if X is the subset of
% triangles from T that are Delaunay triangles for the point set P.
%
% HINT: Define this recursively on the list of triangles T.
%
    delaunay_triangles(T, P, X).


% delaunay_triangulation(P, X) is true if and only if X is the list of Delaunay
% triangles for the point list P.
% HINT: Create temporary variables to describe all triples from P as well as all
% CCW triples from P. Use the predicates you've already defined above!
%
    delaunay_triangulation(P, X).
```

I am not exactly sure what exactly the first four methods exactly mean, if someone could give me that as a start i would be content I'm not asking you to do my assignment either but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `concatenate(L1, L1, T)` is true if and only if `T` is equal to the concatenation of lists `L1` and `L2`.

This should read `concatenate(L1, L2, T)` and is the standard `append/3` predicate. It corresponds to Haskell's `(++)` function for list concatenation. For example, it should behave as follows:

```
?- concatenate([], [1, 2, 3], T).
T = [1, 2, 3].

?- concatenate([1, 2], [3, 4], T).
T = [1, 2, 3, 4].
```

> `singletons(P, Q)` is true if and only if `Q` is equivalent to the list obtained from `P` if each item in `P` is wrapped in "`[`" and "`]`" to create a singleton list.

It looks like this should behave as follows:

```
?- singletons([foo, bar, baz, 42], Singletons).
Singletons = [[foo], [bar], [baz], [42]].
```

You may find this easier to do if you first define an auxiliary predicate that only wraps a single term in a list:

```
?- singleton(foo, Q).
Q = [foo].

?- singleton(foo, [foo]).
true.
```

(You do not need to use this in your definition of `singletons/2`, writing it might just clarify part of the problem.)

> `prefix_all(I, P, Q)` is true if and only if `P` is a list of lists and `Q` is the list obtained by prepending `I` to each element in `P`.

The meaning of this depends on what "prepending" is supposed to mean, but the word `prefix` suggests that `I` is to be interpreted as a list that will be the prefix of any list in `Q`. So something like:

```
?- prefix_all([pre, fix], [[1, 2], [], [foo, bar, baz]], Q).
Q = [[pre, fix, 1, 2], [pre, fix], [pre, fix, foo, bar, baz]].
```

Once again, it may help to think about what it means to be the prefix of *one* list:

```
?- prefix_one([pre, fix], [1, 2], Xs).
Xs = [pre, fix, 1, 2].
```

Do **not** define this predicate! Think about what it means in terms of what you already know.

> `pairs_all(I, P, Q)` is true if and only if `Q` is the list obtained by pairing `I` with each item in `P`.

This looks like it's meant to behave something like this:

```
?- pairs_all(foo, [1, 2, three, 4], Pairs).
Pairs = [ (foo, 1), (foo, 2), (foo, three), (foo, 4)].
```

Again, it may help to first define an auxiliary that constructs a single pair:

```
?- pair(foo, 5, Pair).
Pair = (foo, 5).
```